# Eclipse IDE: Where is Android Remote Device Settings?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using the most up-to-date version of Eclipse (and ADT) and have not been able to find where to add a remote android device for debugging. I'm hoping to use YouWave as the AVD emulator is too slow on my PC. In the past I've been able to add a host and port of my own choosing for a remote device though I can no longer find where to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remote device, you mean ADB enabled physical device on USB or TCP/IP ?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right - with TCP/IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do it from within eclipse. ive been working on a plugin but not ready yet. for now use he command line.

```
adb connect 192.168.1.5:5555
```

you will see it from within eclipse.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have had to teach myself a little about ADB but managed to get it to work. The address I needed was 127.0.0.1:5558 to connect the YouWave emulator

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can refer to this tutorial they have give how to create a Android remote device and also debugging use it **[click here](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/07/debug-remote-android-proces-eclipse/)**

Comment: I used a different answer to solve the question although this link proved to be informative, thank you